# Increasing height increases width

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a game, where the user presses a button to spend money and increase the **height** of a Movie Clip. I use the following: `height ++`.

The problem:  When I test this out, it seems the width increases, too.  The actual thickness, you could say.  How can I solve this?

Comment: You might want to give us more about the implementation. Common objects you're using, how you're applying the change in size and so on.

Comment: The Movie Clip registration is the bottom.  It's called mc.  I call mc.height++  and it increases the height. It also increases(barely) the width.  The movieclip is a rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by selecting the **line** in my movie clip and changing the **scaling** property to **none**.